# Spring Boot Oauth Unautorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, kotlin

I'm trying to follow [this](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/) tutorial in order to get oauth working.

But when I try to make the below request

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=client-id&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=demo&password=1234" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

I get the following error message

```
{"timestamp":"2018-01-25T14:47:42.286+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/oauth/token"}
```

My AuthorizationServerConfiguration looks like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfiguration : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    private val tokenStore: TokenStore? = null

    @Autowired
    private val userApprovalHandler: UserApprovalHandler? = null

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer?) {
        clients!!.inMemory()
                .withClient("client-id")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("secret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120)//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600)//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer?) {
        endpoints!!.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(oauthServer: AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer?) {
        oauthServer!!.realm(REALM + "/client")
    }

    companion object {
        private val REALM = "MY_OAUTH_REALM"
    }
}
```

My ResourceServerConfiguration looks like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfiguration : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(resources: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer?) {
        resources!!.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/users/**")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler())
    }

    companion object {
        private val RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api"
    }

}
```

My OAuth2SecurityConfiguration looks like the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private val clientDetailsService: ClientDetailsService? = null

    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun globalUserDetails(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
                .withUser("demo").password("1234").roles("USER")
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }


    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): TokenStore {
        return InMemoryTokenStore()
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    fun userApprovalHandler(tokenStore: TokenStore): TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler {
        val handler = TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler()
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore)
        handler.setRequestFactory(DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService))
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService)
        return handler
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun approvalStore(tokenStore: TokenStore): ApprovalStore {
        val store = TokenApprovalStore()
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore)
        return store
    }
}
```

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request of token requires Basic Authentication. 
Try to add the following option in your request:

```
-u "client-id:secret"
```

The request:

```
curl -X POST -u "client-id:secret" -d "client_id=client-id&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=demo&password=1234" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

Comment: I suppose it could be trimmed even further: curl -X POST -u "client-id:secret" -d "grant_type=password&username=demo&password=1234" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token. Now I get {"timestamp":"2018-01-25T21:35:12.887+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id \"null\"","path":"/oauth/token"}. Anyway, I'll give you the credits and open a new question.